# how can I replicate working of Multi Label Binarizer from sklearn package in R?

Tags: r, multilabel-classification, confusion-matrix

I want to achieve same working of MultiLabelBinarizer from sklearn.preprocessing package in R. I have list of labels for each example (for Predicated and Actual) like below.

```
[[1]][1] "a"      "b"      "d"    "f"
[[2]][1] "g"      "b"      "f"    "d"
....
```

what I want is to get this in -

`[[1 1 0 1 0 1 ...]
[0 1 0 1 0 1 1 ..]]...`

So that I can get it in the form for multilabel_confusion_matrix.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to convert the source code from `Python` to `R` - see line 289 [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f6924/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py#L890).

You could also check for functionality in existing `R` packages - for instance, `mldr`, `mlr` or `caret` packages.